# Article writing on Stack Overflow

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Should I ask a question I know the answer to?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17463/should-i-ask-a-question-i-know-the-answer-to)

Is there any way to share articles on Stack Overflow similar to [The Code Project](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Code_Project)? There should be, because many users like me want to share useful information on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Is that what Community Wiki is for?

Comment: No, [this is what CW is for](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/08/the-future-of-community-wiki/). @minitech

Comment: Yeppers.  Its called writing an article on [CodeProject](http://codeproject.com)

Answer (score 6):

Generally, no. The exception would be if you have an objective (or "good subjective") question about a real-world programming problem and you know of an article that contains the solution.

Even then, note that you should post the article in an *answer* to the question, not the question itself. Also note that you should actually provide some text about the immediate solution instead of just posting a link to the article by itself.